# Sklearn Logistic Regression predict_proba returning 0 or 1

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I don't have any example data to share in order to replicate the problem, but perhaps someone can provide a high level answer. I've created a lot of logistic regression models in the past, and this is the first time my predict proba scores are showing up as either 1 or 0.

I'm creating a binary classifier to predict one of two labels. I've also used a couple of other algorithms, XGBClassifier and RandomForestCalssifier with the same dataset. For these, predict_proba yields the expected probability results (i.e, float values between 0 and 1).

Also, for the LogisticRegression model, I've tried a variety of parameters including all default params, yet the issue persists. Weirdly enough, using SGDClassifier with loss = 'log' or 'modified_huber' also yields the same binary predict_proba results, so I'm thinking this might be something intrinsic to the dataset, but not sure. Also, this issue only occurs if I standardize training set data. So far I've tried both StandardScaler and MinMaxScaler, same results.

Has anyone ever encountered a problem such as this?

Edit:

The LR parameters are:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.7993269963183343, class_weight='balanced', dual=False,
                   fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=.5,
                   max_iter=100, multi_class='warn', n_jobs=-1, penalty='elasticnet',
                   random_state=58, solver='saga', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```

Again, the issue only occurs when standardizing the data with either `StandardScaler()` or `MinMaxScaler()`. Which is odd because the data is not a uniform scale across all features. For instance, some features are represented as percents, others are represented as dollar values, and others are dummy coded representations.

Comment: Any code available ? Is there an `np.argmax` somewhere ?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code, thank you!

Comment: Can you please give give us information about the solver, penalty, tol, C and max_iter you tried? I think that is crucial to understand your problem.

Comment: @pythonic833 Done.

Comment: @NegativeCorrelation One more thing. Could you please paste the `model.coef_` in here? This way we can check which feature might be responsible for the effect

Comment: You're probably overfitting. What's the accuracy on the training set, what's the log loss? On the test set?

Comment: @AndreasMueller Thought this initially but accuracy was about 60%. When I don't scale, accuracy increases to 87%

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you do the following two things in sequence:

1. Fit an estimator with standardized training data and then later on,
2. Pass unstandardized data to the same estimator in the validation or testing phase.

Here's an example of `predict_proba` returning 0 or 1 using the UCI ML Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) dataset:

```python
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.75, random_state=123)


# Example 1 [CORRECT]
pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Pipeline(steps=[('standardscaler', StandardScaler()), ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression())])
print(pipeline)

y_pred = pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)

# [0.37264656 0.62735344]
print(y_pred.mean(axis=0))



# Example 2 [INCORRECT]
# Fit the model with standardized training set
X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_scaled, y_train)

# Test the model with unstandardized test set
y_pred = model.predict_proba(X_test)

# [1.00000000e+000 2.48303123e-204]
print(y_pred.mean(axis=0))
```

Since the estimator in `Example 2` was fitted on scaled data with a unit variance of 1.0 (`X_scaled`), the variance of the data it's being tested on (`X_test`) is much higher than expected. It's no surprise then that this results in very extreme probabilities.

You can prevent this from happening by wrapping your estimator within a `pipeline` and calling the `pipeline` `fit` method instead of the estimator's `fit` method (see `Example 1`). Doing it this way guarantees that the same transformations are applied to the data in the training, validation and testing phases.